# Calling a function within a function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, asp-classic

I am trying to call the function 'SendAMessageToPerson' when the 'Submit' form is sent. The 'SendAMessageToPerson' is just another Javascript function on the classic ASP page. How do I call a function within a function in Javascript? Sorry - I'm a newbie to Javascript and classic ASP.

//the following is a snippet from the submit function
        if (hasAllergy) {

```
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to include peanuts?")) {
            var checkPersonIsComing = checkPersonIsComing(personId, eventId);
            //checkPersonIsComing function returns a true or false

            if (checkPersonIsComing = 'true')
            {
                alert("True");
                SendAMessageToPerson; //Am I calling this function correctly?
                return true;
            }

            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: change to SendAMessageToPerson();you might also need to pass the parameters if there is any

Comment: And also `checkPersonIsComing === true`...

Comment: In Javascript? Isn't it one equals?

Comment: "=" is assignment operation, "===" is the right way to check for equality

Answer (score 0):

- You need to append `()` to function call to invoke it. Simply typing
  the function name will not actually trigger the function and  use
- Use `==` or `===` rather than `=` .

> `"===" is much more faster than "=="`.

Try this code:

```
function SendAMessageToPerson () {  // I'm sure this function is already made.
    //code here..
}


function anotherFunction () {

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to include peanuts?")) {
        var checkPersonIsComing = checkPersonIsComing(personId, eventId);
        //checkPersonIsComing function returns a true or false

        if (checkPersonIsComing === 'true') // = is for assignment and == or === is for comparison
        {
            alert("True");
            SendAMessageToPerson(); //This is the correct way to call a function.
            return true;
        }

        else {
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `checkPersonIsComing` function is lost when you assign its result to a variable of the same name.  It will be restored once you exit the function (assuming your code is within a function.)

If `checkPersonIsComing` returns a boolean true/false, you can test it like this:

```
if(checkPersonIsComing(personId, eventId))
```

This is equivalent to this:

```
if(checkPersonIsComing(personId, eventId) === true)
```

Here's a simplified version, which also corrects the `SendAMessageToPerson` call by adding parentheses:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to include peanuts?")) {
    if(checkPersonIsComing(personId, eventId)) {
        alert("True");
        SendAMessageToPerson();
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If `SendAMessageToPerson` expects a parameter, place it between the parentheses.

It's also good practice to be consistent with camelCase.  Consider renaming `SendAMessageToPerson` as `sendAMessageToPerson`.

Answer (score 0):

you're not calling your function correctly.
function calling is always done like

```
SendAMessageToPerson( <parameters if any> );  <------- Notice these brackets.
```

So make your call as **SendAMessageToPerson();**
also your if condition is not formed correctly. if you are writing

```
if (checkPersonIsComing = 'true')
```

don't you think this statement is identical to assigning a variable "**checkPersonComing**" to the value '**true**'. So this when putting inside the if statement always return TRUE.

To make it a condition use === rather than =.

Answer (score 0):

alert is a function you are already calling from within your function that takes one parameter ( the string to alert ) ...

So you do similar thing for your function...
SendAMessageToPerson();

If your function has no parameters then above will work, or else you add in the parameters function needs...

SendAMessageToPerson( param1, param2);